# how to statistics for each item in file xml by python

Tags: python, xml

I have a lot of xml files like this

```
<object>
    <name>VaccumA</name>
</object>
<object>
    <name>VaccumA</name>
</object>
<object>
    <name>VaccumB</name>
</object>
<object>
    <name>VaccumB</name>
</object>
<object>
    <name>VaccumB</name>
</object>
<object>
    <name>Vaccum</name>
</object>
<object>
    <name>VaccumC</name>
</object>
```

I can count name but I can't count each type

```
 from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
 file = open('file.xml','r')
 data = file.read()
 file.close()
 print (len(dom.getElementsByTagName('name')))
```

How can I statistics VaccumA, VaccumB, VaccumC in all files xml

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not exactly clear what you want to accomplish from your question. Could you clarify what you mean by "statistics"? [This guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions might be helpful if you haven't read it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should work (per 1 xml). Your job is to load all xml files you need to scan and loop over them.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<r><object>
    <name>VaccumA</name>
</object>
<object>
    <name>VaccumA</name>
</object>
<object>
    <name>VaccumB</name>
</object>
<object>
    <name>VaccumB</name>
</object>
<object>
    <name>VaccumB</name>
</object>
<object>
    <name>Vaccum</name>
</object>
<object>
    <name>VaccumC</name>
</object></r>'''

data = defaultdict(int)
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for name in root.findall('.//name'):
    data[name.text] += 1
print(data)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'VaccumA': 2, 'VaccumB': 3, 'Vaccum': 1, 'VaccumC': 1})
```

Comment: plz tell me way to open file xml in path

Comment: Try to find out yourself.